# Map Activity with real time location update

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to create a map activity that displays the user current location that can be zoomed to street level but my app is not working properly, what do you think are the codes that I need to add?

```
public class Map_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    private LocationClient myLocationClient;
    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(5000)
            .setFastestInterval(16)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        getMapReference();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        getMapReference();
        wakeUpLocationClient();
        myLocationClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (myLocationClient != null){
            myLocationClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    private void gotoMyLocation(double lat, double lng) {
        changeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                        .zoom(15.5f)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .tilt(25)
                        .build()
        ), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });
    }
    private void wakeUpLocationClient(){
        if(myLocationClient == null){
            myLocationClient = new LocationClient(getApplicationContext(),this,this);
        }
    }
    private void getMapReference(){
        if(myMap==null){
            myMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        if (myMap != null){
            myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
        myLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates( REQUEST, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult){

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void changeCamera(CameraUpdate update, GoogleMap.CancelableCallback callback) {

        myMap.moveCamera(update);
    }
}
```

the app is running but the map is not showing and it is not showing me my current location :( i hope somebody could help me

Comment: You are not getting the map because you are not "getting the map". You need call `getMapAsync()` and implement the `onMapReadyCallBack()` callback [according to the official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro). Maybe someone will write a proper answer explaining that in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here are step by step for using GoogleMaps:

A.configured your project to work with GoogleMaps (your map may not appear if not properly configured):

1. in "build.graddle" add dependencies with proper version e.g. 6.5.87 or 8.1.0:
   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`
2. in "Android.Manifest" add permissions, GL and API Key (make sure to put your APIKey):

   `< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   < uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true"/>
     <!-- Google Maps Fragment API Key Data -->
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="YOUR API KEY" />
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

B. Code:

1. use OnMapReady :

   - add "OnMapReadyCallback" to your activity class:
     `public class Map_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
     GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
     com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,
     OnMapReadyCallback
     {`
   - override onMapReady to enable location and have reference to GoogleMap:

     `@Override
     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
     map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     googleMap = map;
     }`
2. in Activity-OnCrate call getMapAsync:

   `FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

C. Remove/replace deprecated code:

```
-LocationClient
-replace "GooglePlayServicesClient" with GoogleApiClient
```